# TFS 2015 with SQL Server 2014. Best migration path to upgrade to Azure DevOps 2019?

Tags: azure-devops, tfs-2015

I am currently running TFS 2015 Update 3 with a SQL Server 2014 backend database environment.

It appears that SQL 2014 isn't supported with Azure DevOps 2019, so an in-place upgrade of TFS 2015 to 2019 may not be supported.

I have a separate SQL Server 2017 environment set up on a different server.   My initial thought was to migrate TFS 2015 databases from SQL 2014 to SQL 2017 and then perform the upgrade.   However, TFS 2015 doesn't support SQL 2017 (based on [system requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/requirements?view=azure-devops) doc)

What would be the best migration path to upgrade from TFS 2015 to Azure DevOps 2019 while on SQL 2014 and only having SQL 2017 as an option?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> TFS 2015 with SQL Server 2014. Best migration path to upgrade to Azure DevOps 2019?

You could upgrade your TFS application and your SQL serverl separately, not necessarily as a whole.

According to the document [Upgrade your deployment to the latest version of Azure DevOps Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/upgrade/get-started?view=azure-devops), we could upgrade the TFS 2015 to Azure DevOps Server 2019:

[image]

So, we could:

- Upgrade from SQL Server 2014 to SQL Server 2017
- Migration from TFS 2015 to Azure DevOps Server 2019
- Select the SQL Server 2017 when you configure databases

Note: Do not forget to backup all your data before upgrading.

You could check [this document](https://www.aspiresys.com/articles/Migration-from-TFS-2015-to-2018.pdf) and [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/upgrade/get-started?view=azure-devops) for some more details.

Hope this helps.